# @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am working on Spring boot Security and when I want to run it, I found an error that

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: xxxxxxxxxx [java.security.Permission]
```

I don't know how to fix this and I'm new to Spring.
Thanks for reading and spending time.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLES")
public class Role implements Serializable, GrantedAuthority {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;    

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "role_permissions",
            joinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
            inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
            )

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Set <Permission> permission;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Permission> getPermission() {
        return permission;
    }

    public void setPermission(Set<Permission> permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
    }

    public Role() {}

    public Role(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Role [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", permission=" + permission + "]";
    }

}
```

permission class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERMISSIONS")
public class Permissions implements GrantedAuthority {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Permissions() {}
    public Permissions( String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "permissions [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: would you please add permission java class too?

Comment: I added Permission class

Comment: Is the class name `Permission` or `Permissions`

Comment: Looking at the error message it seems clear you have imported the wrong class to Role  - java.security.Permission - rather than your.package.Permission

Comment: It's Permissions :)

Comment: This error is perfectly obvious. Change `Set<Permission>` to `Set<Permissions>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making wrong `Set<Permission>` that is `java.security.Permission`. So change it to `Set<Permissions>` that is your own class file.